# How to add a new User setting in run time?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, settings

I would like to know how to add a new User Setting in C sharp during the run time. How can new values be inserted dynamically?  Thanks in advance

Comment: Where you want to add new values?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175726/c-create-new-settings-at-run-time

Answer (score 0):

> Settings can represent user preferences, or valuable information the
> application needs to use.

Adding a new setting:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add("property_name",Color.AliceBlue); 
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Editing an existing setting:

```
Properties.Settings.Default["property_name"]=Color.Green;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Retrieving

```
Color backColor = Properties.Settings.Default["property_name"] as Color;
```

Deleting an existing setting:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Remove("property_name"); 
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```