# Save method is not working on New Setting Property

Tags: c#, application-settings

I have a big project with many sub projects. 
For a specific sub project, I want to create user settings at run time.

I have initialized the settings file with one dummy Setting.

Why the settings are not getting saved into the Settings file ?

Some articles suggest to Set User-Scope ? I have no idea how to do that.

I have tested this code in a test project on its own. It behaved the same, not saving the setting.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

I'm stuck. Can someone really help ?

Thank you

```
try  
{    
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Properties.Settings.Default["mySetting"].ToString()))    
    {
        //Do something here
    }    
}
catch (Exception)
{
    SettingsProperty AProperty = new SettingsProperty("mySetting");

    AProperty.PropertyType = typeof(bool);
    AProperty.IsReadOnly = false;
    AProperty.DefaultValue = false;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add(AProperty);
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
    var testSettings = Properties.Settings.Default["mySetting"]; //Exception
}
```

I have used the following code to figure out the location of the user.config file.
I have looked at it and I found there are new Settings are added to this file.
However, if I modify an existing setting, the update would save this file.

```
var path = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal).FilePath;
```

Comment: Please ask **one** question per question.  Not four.  See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts) for more information.

Comment: Amy, these questions are the issues :)

Comment: Amy, I reduced my questions to one. I will ask the rest in different posts as per rules.

Comment: Here, have an upvote, and welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you Amy :) That was a warm welcoming gesture.

Comment: Your code looks fine to me (I haven't run it locally).  Can you check that you're examining the correct config file?  It will modify the one in your bin directory, not the one in the project root.

Comment: Amy, I have examined the **.exe.config** files in the *bin/Debug* and *bin/Release* folders. I have ran the project in both Release and Debug mode to make sure. Same issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/175726

Comment: Application settings are read-only, and you can't add user settings dynamically.  You can change the _value_ at run-time but not add a setting dynamically.

Comment: How could a user setting added dynamically ? From the comments I got, I'm doing the right thing. I'm confused now :)